# Java - fill list values with other list as function parameter using recursion

Tags: java, list, recursion

In my java function i want to use a list as parameter, like List 1 = (a,b,c).
Where every value is a value from another list, List 2 = (1, 2, 3). Now i want to call my function with every possible combination to fill it.

Like a=1, b=1, c=1; a=1, b=2, c=1; a=1, b=3, c=1, etc.

Problem is the list length for either is changed every time the function is called.

Usually i would use two for loops, or a simple function with recursion. 
But i dont know how exactly to deal with the changing list length. Perhaps my question was to broad, my problem is in not knowing how to change just one value in the list, until every combination is called.

The function i imagine looks something like this: 
(i know the function with a for loop will not work, i must use an iterator)

```
List 1 = (a,b,c);
List 2 = (1,2,3);
list1.set(a, 1);
list1.set(b, 1);
list1.set(c, 1);

functionFillList(List list1){
  for(Element e : list1){
   //do something
   //in some cases add elements to list2
  }
  //change one value of list1
  functionFillList(list1);
 //if every combination was called -> end function
}
```

Comment: In what way do the lists change? Are new elements appended or deleted at the end or are some updated or changed in between or at the front? And if you visited all elements of list 2 for one element of list 1 and then add an element to list 2, do you need to calculate those missing permutations as well? And how/why are the lists changed?

Comment: list 2 which holds the values for the combination is changed in the function itself.  With the iterator, you just need to add the element itself to the iterator. In the end i will likely use the iterator, but for simplicity i used a for loop here.

Comment: what is the final result you want

Comment: i want to look if the combination meets a certain condition. And then add a new element to list2.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop for changing the data of the list will throw concurrent modification error, use `Iterator` instead of loop to change the list data. Iterator allows to modify the data.

```
void functionFillList(List list1){
      Iterator<String> iter = list1.iterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()){
       //do something
      }
      //change one value of list1
      functionFillList(list1);
     //if every combination was called -> end function
    }
```